# Using JavaScript Reduce to generate an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

I have an array of numbers `[22, 44, 12, 9, 4, 23, 1, 11, 10, 5, 2, 123]`, I need to use reduce to create an object that looks like this:

```js
{  
   numbersLessThanTen: [...],  
   numbersGreaterThanTen: [...]
}
```

I have the solution, which is the below:

```js
const listOfNumbers = [22, 44, 12, 9, 4, 23, 1, 11, 10, 5, 2, 123];


const groupedBySize = listOfNumbers.reduce((total, next) => {
  const less = total.numbersLessThanTen || [];
  const more = total.numbersGreaterThanTen || [];
  
  next > 10 ? total.numbersGreaterThanTen = [].concat(more, next) : total.numbersLessThanTen = [].concat(less, next);
  return total;
  
}, {});
```

My question is, why does the following not work? It just returns the initial value. It works when I use .push() instead of .concat() but I really want to understand why this way does not work. Thank you!

```js
const groupedBySize = listOfNumbers.reduce((total, next) => {
  // const less = total.numbersLessThanTen || [];
  // const more = total.numbersGreaterThanTen || [];
  
  next > 10 ? total.numbersGreaterThanTen.concat(next) : total.numbersLessThanTen.concat(next);
  return total;

}, {numbersGreaterThanTen: [], numbersLessThanTen:[]});
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! They were all informative answers, I just found the way Akrion's solution read was more suitable for me personally

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is becase `concat()` returns the result of concatentation as a new array. When your reduce function runs, the concatentation work is done, but the result of that concatentation isn't  assigned to anything (ie a field in `total`). This is the reason the output result appears is identical to the input - the arrays in `total` never actually get updated. The [following is from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#Description)

> The concat method creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on which it is called.

The `push()` method on the other hand actually mutates/updates the array that it's called on, adding what ever data you pass directly to that array instance. This means when `push()` is called per iteration, the arrays in `total` are updated directly which is why this approach works:

> The push method appends values to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Others explained why that approach didn't work, and gave reasonable answers, continuing the mutation.

Here is an approach that doesn't mutate any data:

```js
const listOfNumbers = [22, 44, 12, 9, 4, 23, 1, 11, 10, 5, 2, 123];

const groupedBySize = nbr => nbr.reduce 
  ( ({ gt10, lte10 }, next) => next > 10 
     ? { gt10: gt10 .concat(next), lte10 } 
     : { gt10, lte10: lte10 .concat(next) }
  , { gt10: [], lte10: [] }
  )

console.log(groupedBySize(listOfNumbers))
```

I also shorted the property names.  Obviously you could re-lengthen them.  But do note that `"numbersLessThanTen"` is a bit misleading, as it includes `10`.

Answer (score 1):

You can decide which array with the ternary and then `push()` instead of `concat()`:

```js
let n = [22, 44, 12, 9, 4, 23, 1, 11, 10, 5, 2, 123]

let obj = n.reduce((obj, n) => {
    (n < 10 
     ? obj.numbersLessThanTen
     : obj.numbersGreaterThanTen
    ).push(n)
    return obj
}, {numbersLessThanTen: [],  numbersGreaterThanTen:[]})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I was scrolling down to add this exact answer. Too late.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does not **mutate** the array on which it is called. You are assuming that and not assigning the result to anything ... as per docs:

> This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a
>   new array

So to get what you want with your code you could do something like this:

```js
const listOfNumbers = [22, 44, 12, 9, 4, 23, 1, 11, 10, 5, 2, 123];

const groupedBySize = listOfNumbers.reduce((total, next) => {  
  let key = next > 10 ? 'numbersGreaterThanTen' : 'numbersLessThanTen'
  total[key] = total[key].concat([next]); // <-- assign the result
  return total;
}, {numbersGreaterThanTen: [], numbersLessThanTen: []});

console.log(groupedBySize)
```

Alternatively you could just do this:

```js
const listOfNumbers = [22, 44, 12, 9, 4, 23, 1, 11, 10, 5, 2, 123];

const groupedBySize = listOfNumbers.reduce((ttl, nxt) => 
 (ttl[nxt > 10 ? 'numbersGreaterThanTen' : 'numbersLessThanTen'].push(nxt), ttl), 
 {numbersGreaterThanTen: [], numbersLessThanTen:[]});

console.log(groupedBySize)
```

Which does the same thing but uses [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which `mutates` the array on which it is called by inserting the item.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solutions, I understood that concat does not mutate the array but I see now my problem was assuming that reduce accumulated the two arrays for me and that I would have access to the new concated arrays in the next iteration. I like the way your solution reads better than mine!